# Styling an SVG tile layer with CSS in Leaflet

Tags: css, svg, leaflet, vector-tiles

I use Leaflet to display a vector tile layer, like this:

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer('mytiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.svg', {
    renderer: L.svg(),
    continuousWorld: true,
    noWrap: true,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 10,
})
```

The elements of my tiles have CSS classes, such as `<rect class="country-ES" ...></rect>`, so I would like to style them in my CSS:

```
.country-ES {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

However, the tiles do not seem to be affected by these CSS instructions. And I do not know how to debug this as the tiles cannot be inspected by the web developper tools of Chrome or Firefox.

Any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: Put the CSS in the SVG file or link the SVG file to the CSS file.

Comment: I want to be able to change the styling on the fly by adding CSS classes to my map. For instance, I could use `.highlight-country .country-ES { fill: red !important; }`, so that the style is only applied when my map has the `highlight-country` class.

Comment: inline SVG will be easier, otherwise you'd have to inject the CSS into the SVG at runtime.

Comment: yes, exactly, I want Leaflet to display my tiles as inline SVG… but I have not figured out yet how to do that. I am trying to overload the createTiles method so that it downloads the tile and puts it in an `<svg>` element, I'll post an answer if that works…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `renderer: L.svg()` in the tiles has no effect (this is meant for the overlay elements in the map).

I had to force Leaflet to display the tiles as embedded SVG, like this:

```
tiles.createTile = function (coords, done) {
    var tile = document.createElement('div');

    tile.setAttribute('role', 'presentation');

    $.get(this.getTileUrl(coords),
         success=function(data) {
             tile.appendChild(data.firstChild);
             done(null, tile);
    }).fail(function(error) {
             done(error, tile);
    });

    return tile;
};
```

And then it worked!

Comment: This is a very nice approach! You could actually create a small plugin, wrapping that in something like `L.TileLayer.SVG = L.TileLayer.extend({ createTile: function(coords, tile){...} })`. Creating a subclass of `L.TileLayer` can be good for organizing the code a bit better.

Comment: @IvanSanchez : yes i am thinking about it, but the method still has a few drawbacks: letting the browser manage the loading and caching of `<img>` elements gives a more fluid rendering. I will try to overcome these.